# Wordpress admin styles being applied to front end

Tags: css, wordpress, frontend

So, out of the blue, a bunch of styles from the `wp-admin` and `wp-include` folders are being enqueued in the front end, I have disabled all the pluggins and all my css and still, i'm going mad.
[image]

Comment: Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: ¬¬ of course...

Comment: @penHolder can you clarify what's happening on the front end, some of these scripts are injected by `wp_head` when you're logged in. Also if you're using a custom theme, provide us with how you're enqueuing styles in functions.php, And try seeing if you're encountering the issue when switching to a default theme.

Comment: @pj100 currently i'm not using any theme, i'm building from scratch, i'm not enqueing any styles yet, all those styles are destined to the dashboard not the actual site, so thats why _I`m going mad_

Comment: @penHolder yeah these really aren't atypical though. these are being injected by `wp_head`. Unless it's causing you some type of issue on the front end, this isn't a problem. `wp_head` injects all of this due to the admin bar, and utilities provied while logged in.

Comment: yeah, though of that, but even i've disabled the admin bar and logged out, stays the same, some dark magic's happening here

Answer (score 0):

You can disable various scripts step by step (not just plugins), so you can find the culprit. I mean: included files, functions calls, procedures.